# How to send HTTP request from Twilio Flow to GoogleSheet (via Sheety API)

Tags: google-sheets, twilio, http-post

i have all my twilio flow working (WhatsApp ChatBot) but i can't manage to handle the post request to GoogleSheet that would include the result of the conversation.

My JSON in the body look good to me (datum is name for the sheet and all column are in small char)

Anyone could help me with this struggle? I real the Sheety + Twilio documentation but it is not really helfull.. Thanks a lot !!!
[image: Flow]
[image: Flow HTTP Request]

I manage to send the POST request via API directly from Pycharm but I can't manage to send the request via Twilio HTTP POST request

I have the following error message from twilio :

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "detail": "Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution !! Kinf of stupid but ... I just needed to replace the ' in the JSON by "

Happy coding to you all, I hope this post can help a fellow dev